# Why is the code giving me "(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status" as an error?

Tags: c, error-handling

I'm trying to display an array using a "data.txt." file, that I have not included simply because it's too long.
My code looks like this but when I compile/linking it keeps giving me
"(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status". Does anyone know why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ROW 366

int main(void) {
   FILE *ptr;
   ptr = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    
   int count, i, j;
   double arr[ROW][6];
   int day[ROW];
    
   while (fscanf(ptr, "%d", &count) != EOF) {
      for(i=0; i<ROW; i++) {
         fscanf(ptr, "%d", &day[i]);
         for(j=0; j<6; j++) {
            fscanf(ptr, "%lf", &arr[i][j]);
         }
      }
   }
    
   for(i=0; i<ROW; i++) {
      for(j=0; j<6; j++) {
         printf(" %lf", arr[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
    
   return (0);
}
```

I looked at all the semicolons and asked a friend but not able to find the solution

Comment: What is the command that you are using to compile main.c?

Comment: The error indicated is a compile/linking time. For example, for compiling your program saved on file test.c with gcc, you must run:

gcc test.c -o test

Comment: Unrelated: prefer `while (fscanf(ptr, "%d", &count) == 1)` or even better, use `fgets()` instead of `fscanf()` throughout your code.